# How to convert json object with objects to json array with objects

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2, okhttp

I have a json object that looks like this.

```
{
  "Items": {
    "zzzz": {
      "id": "zzzz",
      "title": "qqqqqqq",
      "notifications": []
    },
    "rrrrr": {
      "id": "rrrrr",
      "title": "rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr",
      "notifications": []
    },
    "eeeee": {
      "id": "eeeee",
      "title": "eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee",
      "notifications": []
    },
    "wwww": null,
    "dddddd": {
      "id": "dddddd",
      "title": "ddddddddddddddddddddddddd",
      "notifications": []
    },
    "qqq": {
      "id": "qqq",
      "title": "qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq",
      "notifications": []
    },
    "rrrrrr": null
  }
}
```

My data class:

```
data class Response( 
                    val Items: List<Notification>
                    ........)
data ckass Notification(
                    val id : String,
                    val title: String,
                    val notifications: List<...>,
```

I need a List with objects zzzz,rrrr and so on to get into the data class with val items. But I can't figure out how to convert the incoming json object to a json array

I wanted to use my own deserializer, but in my case it won't help because I use one instance of okhttp and retrofit for all requests. And also, a response always comes from the server in the form of:

```
  "Items": {
       //other request body
  },
.....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what deserializer you using.  Here's a solution assuming Jackson, but maybe you can take the ideas from this if you are using Gson, etc.

The key idea is to use an intermediary object to deserialize into - a Map whose key values you ignore:

```
// your desired data classes
data class Response(
    val items: List<Notification>,
)

data class Notification(
    val id: String,
    val title: String,
    val notifications: List<Any>,
)

// an intermediary object
// I notice that some Notifications are null, hence the `?`
data class ResponseWithObjects(
    @JsonProperty("Items") // this is needed for Jackson since I used a conventional variable name Kotlin side
    val items: Map<String, Notification?>,
)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val actualResponse: ResponseWithObjects = TestUtils.deserialize("/test.json", ResponseWithObjects::class)
    println(actualResponse)
    val desiredResponse = Response(
        items = actualResponse.items
            .values.filterNotNull() // assuming you don't want the null notifications in the resultant array
            .toList(),
    )
    println(desiredResponse)
}
```

Comment: yep, I managed to do about the same thing, only with json)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To convert the given JSON object to a list of Notification objects, you can iterate over the key-value pairs in the "Items" object and create a Notification object for each non-null value. Here's some sample Kotlin code that demonstrates this:

```kotlin
    val json = // the JSON object from your example
    val itemsObject = json.getJSONObject("Items")
    val notifications = mutableListOf<Notification>()
    for (key in itemsObject.keys()) {
        val item = itemsObject.getJSONObject(key)
        if (item != null) {
            val notification = Notification(
                item.getString("id"),
                item.getString("title"),
                // add logic to parse notifications list here
            )
            notifications.add(notification)
        }
    }
    val response = Response(notifications)
```

Note that you'll need to fill in the logic to parse the "notifications" list for each Notification object. If it's just an array of strings, you can use `item.getJSONArray("notifications").toList()` to get a list of strings.

Comment: Perhaps, but I get a response from the server already in the form of a class, again, I repeat. Writing my deserializer does not suit me, because different answers come to the `Items` object, and it is not possible to use different okhttp clients and so on